# Make ReSharper reformat code according to StyleCop rule SA1206: The 'static' keyword must come before the 'other' keyword in the element declaration

Tags: resharper

I suspect I should create a pattern in *ReSharper / Options / Languages / C# / Formatting Style / Type Membership Layout* for this. I am currently using the default pattern and I would like some help from someone who is good at them.

I want this to be **WRONG**:

```
public new static Age Empty {
    get {
        return empty;
    }

    set {
        empty = value;
    }
}
```

And this to be **right**:

```
public static new Age Empty {
    get {
        return empty;
    }

    set {
        empty = value;
    }
}
```

In other words, I want static to come before other keywords, like new. Currently ReSharper 5.1 does it the "wrong" way.

Comment: It seems like it could be expressed with a pattern in ReSharper. Have you used ReSharper 5.1 and know the limitations of the patterns?

Comment: If it's wrong, have you reported this to JetBrains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible.

Answer (score 3):

ReSharper now has the possibility to configure the arrangement of modifiers.

Open the ReSharper options and go to *Code Editing | C# | Code Style*. In the *Modifiers* section *Modifiers order* you can reorder the arrangement according to your needs (see ReSharper online help: [Arranging Modifiers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Modifiers_Style.html)).

To satisfy StyleCop's rule SA1206 move the `static` modifier above the `new` modifier:
[image: modifier order]

Comment: Also, if the keyword isn't in the list (like the new `required` keyword) you can add it by editing the DotSettings file directly after changing the default ordering in the UI